# Sort a list of dates using C#

Tags: c#, list, sorting, date

I got a list of entries with a `date`, a `text` and a `finished` attribute.

I want to sort this list by the `date`. The date has the following format: `dd.mm.yyyy`

If I run this code, the result is mixed up like nothing happened. What's wrong?

this is my code:

```
// in the namespace
struct entry
{
    public string date;
    public string text;
    public bool finished;

    public entry(string _date, string _text, bool _finished)
    {
        date = _date;
        text = _text;
        finished = _finished;
    }
}

// in my class
List<entry> entrys = new List<entry>();

// ** fill the list with content **

// where i want to sort the list
entrys.Sort(delegate (entry x, entry y)
{
    string date1 = x.date;
    string date2 = y.date;

    // 0123456789
    // dd.mm.yyyy

    int day1 = Convert.ToInt32(date1.Substring(0, 2));
    int day2 = Convert.ToInt32(date2.Substring(0, 2));

    int month1 = Convert.ToInt32(date1.Substring(3, 2));
    int month2 = Convert.ToInt32(date2.Substring(3, 2));

    int year1 = Convert.ToInt32(date1.Substring(6, 4));
    int year2 = Convert.ToInt32(date2.Substring(6, 4));

    if (year1 > year2) return -1;
    if (month1 > month2) return -1;
    if (day1 > day2) return -1;

    return 1;
});
```

Comment: not an answer but your method never returns 0 in case that both are equals

Comment: What happens if year1 < year2 ?

Comment: Any reason you are using a string to store a date rather than a Date type? that can do a data compare with another date for you.

Comment: Stringly typed code is just wrong thing to look for... (also to completely follow the "stringly typed" mantra you should not use bool either). :) What's wrong with using proper `DateTime` for the type itself, or at least in comparison method?

Comment: omg i am just stupid, i somehow thought that if year1 > year2 is false, that year1 !< year2 :)

Comment: And mandatory XKCD link as you work with dates: http://xkcd.com/1179/

Answer (score 2):

You're really doing this the hard way:

```
var entries = new List<entry>();
// ** fill the list with content **

entries = entries.OrderBy(e => DateTime.ParseExact(e.date, "dd.MM.yyyy", null)).ToList();
```

And one wonders why you don't already have `.date` property as a `DateTime` type instead of a string.

Comment: +1. Cleanest solution IMO. Note to the OP that this answer uses [LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx) so you should add `using System.Linq;` to your using statements.

Answer (score 1):

Your date field should become a DateTime. However, if for some reason you need it to be a string, then do the following:

First, add a GetDate method to your entry structure:

```
public DateTime GetDate()
{
    int day = Convert.ToInt32(date.Substring(0, 2));

    int month = Convert.ToInt32(date.Substring(3, 2));

    int year = Convert.ToInt32(date.Substring(6, 4));

    return new DateTime(year,month,day);
}
```

Then, use the following when you sort:

```
entrys.Sort((x, y) => x.GetDate().CompareTo(y.GetDate()));
```

Answer (score 0):

this code works:

```
entrys.Sort(delegate (entry x, entry y)
        {
            string date1 = x.date;
            string date2 = y.date;

            // 0123456789
            // dd.mm.yyyy

            int day1 = Convert.ToInt32(date1.Substring(0, 2));
            int day2 = Convert.ToInt32(date2.Substring(0, 2));

            int month1 = Convert.ToInt32(date1.Substring(3, 2));
            int month2 = Convert.ToInt32(date2.Substring(3, 2));

            int year1 = Convert.ToInt32(date1.Substring(6, 4));
            int year2 = Convert.ToInt32(date2.Substring(6, 4));

            if (year1 > year2) return 1;
            if (year1 == year2 && month1 > month2) return 1;
            if (year1 == year2 && month1 == month2 && day1 > day2) return 1;

            return -1;
        });
```

Comment: This is not how one *should* have solved the problem. Number of string operations executed unnecessarily is way too high. Ignoring the fact there is exact type that deals with Date values in C#./.Net

Comment: This will swap two dates if they are equals. assuming you have `d1,d2,d3,d4`. and if `d2` and `d3` are equal when you sort it will become `d1,d3,d2,d4` and if you sort this again it will change back to `d1,d2,d3,d4`. because there is no 0 return to indicate two dates are equal

Comment: i suggest you use the built in .Net DateTime class and its compare method and features.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary returning 0 really only matters if OP is looking for stable sort, but since `List<T>.Sort` "This implementation performs an unstable sort; " - it does not matter in this particular case.

Answer (score 0):

Always follow the KISS (Keep It Simple Stupid) principle:

```
entrys.Sort(delegate (entry x, entry y)
{
    DateTime dt1 = DateTime.ParseExact(x.date, "dd.MM.yyyy", 
          CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    DateTime dt2 = DateTime.ParseExact(y.date, "dd.MM.yyyy", 
          CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    return DateTime.Compare(dt1, dt2);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to manually parse strings if computer can do that for you:

```
var provider = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
entrys.Sort((a, b) => 
    DateTime.ParseExact(a.date, "dd.MM.yyyy", provider)
        .CompareTo(DateTime.ParseExact(b.date, "dd.MM.yyyy", provider)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just typed this quickly in [LinqPad](http://linqpad.net), the idea is to use Linq OrdeBy and defining a get property on the struct/class to return parsed `DateTime`. You can use `TryPraseExact` for additional safety.

```
void Main()
{
var list = new List<Entity>{
    new Entity{TempDate = "25.10.2015", SomeData="data1"},
    new Entity{TempDate = "20.10.2015", SomeData="data2"},
    new Entity{TempDate = "26.10.2015", SomeData="data3"},
    new Entity{TempDate = "18.10.2015", SomeData="data4"}};

list.Dump("Original");

list.OrderBy(x => x.DateTimeParsed).Dump("Sorted");
}

public struct Entity
{
public string TempDate {get; set;}
public DateTime DateTimeParsed{ get{ return DateTime.ParseExact(TempDate, "dd.mm.yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); }}

public string SomeData {get; set;}
}
```

It is also a good idea to pass around `DateTimeOffset` instead of a string date